# positive matrices diagonalised by involutions

Tags: diagonalization, positive-definite, involutions

Let $A$ be a positive definite matrix. Then $A$ is diagonalized by an orthogonal matrix $P$.

I want to know, when this matrix is also an involution. ie. $P^2 = I$.

If there is any characterization of such $A$ kindly share.

Thank you.

Comment: This cannot be the case in general, since $P$ will be orthonormal, i.e., $P^TP=I$. This would mean that $P$ itself is the identity, which only is the case for diagonal matrices $A$.

Comment: @User123456789 How $P$ is identity? your reasoning shows that $P$ is symmetric. can you please explain?

Comment: Now I think of it, $P$ indeed not needs to be the identity, but it should be a permutation type matrix. For example $P = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1\\1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$. The point being that it cannot be any general vector. For $P$ to be orthonormal, it needs to be of the form (in 2D, for easy visualisation) $P = \begin{pmatrix} a & b\\ -b & a\end{pmatrix}$. Note that the columns can be swapped since this does not change the basis. As you can see from this form, $P$ can only be symmetric if $-b=b=0$, meaning $P$ is diagonal, and since $P$ is orthonormal, the diagonal entries should be $\pm 1$.